# Is there any dynamixel pro ROS code?

Tags: dynamixel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can anyone tell me where I can get the ROS code for dynamixel pro?
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/157251/is-there-any-dynamixel-pro-ros-code?/) by [Jong H Kim](https://answers.ros.org/users/1617/jong-h-kim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2014-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Brian Axelrod wrote a dynamixel pro driver and controller. It isn't documented on the ROS wiki, but it is available on his [github account](https://github.com/baxelrod?tab=repositories), and it should be released into hydro as `ros-hydro-dynamixel-pro-driver` and `ros-hydro-dynamixel-pro-controller`.

I haven't used these drivers personally, so I can't help you use them, and I'm not sure how well they work.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jong H Kim](https://answers.ros.org/users/1617/jong-h-kim/) on 2014-04-25**:
Great Thank you very much. :)

**Comment by [Jong H Kim](https://answers.ros.org/users/1617/jong-h-kim/) on 2014-04-25**:
Can you tell me how to install the dynamixel pro driver and controller?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-04-28**:
No, really, I can't help you with it.

**Comment by [Jong H Kim](https://answers.ros.org/users/1617/jong-h-kim/) on 2014-04-29**:
Is there any explanation ffor the pro like the dynamixel installation posted in ROS at http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_motor? With that information, I can install and run it.
Thanks.

**Comment by [RohitM](https://answers.ros.org/users/26985/rohitm/) on 2016-05-30**:
Has it worked for anyone yet? And does ROS Indigo also support these packages?